# Make 1D array of pointers pointing towards an Object in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, 2d

I don't get what is wrong. I am trying to get one pointer to use the adress of another one to get to an Object which is created at start.

```
class Soldier{
public:
    Soldier(char c){
        type = c;
    }
char type;
};

//a 2d vector of armies and its soldiers 
vector< vector<Soldier> > *armys = new vector< vector<Soldier> >(3, vector<Soldier>(5, Soldier('@')));
//making a pointer array 
Soldier **deployment = new Soldier*[3*5];

//test if it works: 
//show the original value 
cout << "the third soldier of the first army is of type " << (*armys)[1][2].type << endl;  
//initializing the pointers of the deployment array to make them point to the Object through the vector.  
(*deployment)[1 * (armys->size()) + 2] = (*armys)[1][2];
//show the value via the pointer
cout << "the third soldier of the first army is of type " << (*deployment)[1 * (armys->size()) + 2].type << endl;
```

The code above triggers a segmentation fault before showing the second message.

Comment: Don't use dynamic arrays when you have `std::vector`.

Comment: Possibly different issues. The one I see is: armys->size() returns the number of armies, what you want is the size of each army.

Comment: `(*deployment)[1 * (armys->size()) + 2]` is a `Soldier`, not a pointer. At least it would have been if there were a valid object there - it's equivalent to `deployment[0][1 * (armys->size()) + 2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why doesn't it work ?

In the following statement, you copy a `Soldier` object to the location of an unitialized pointer.  This can only go wrong:

```
     (*deployment)[1 * (armys->size()) + 2] = (*armys)[1][2];
```

### How to fix it ?

`deployment` is a 1D array of 3*5 pointers.  So you have to first initialize the pointers in the array element (and not copy the object):

```
     deployment[1 * (armys->size()) + 2] = &(*armys)[1][2];  // take address of armys element
```

Then you can refer to your `Soldier` object via pointer indirection:

```
     cout << "the third soldier of the first army is of type " 
          << deployment[1 * (armys->size()) + 2]->type << endl;
```

Keep in mind that with `Soldier **deployment`,  `deployment[i]` will be a pointer to a `Soldier`.

### Is this all ?

While the corrected code works, the way you calculate the index in your 1D array might give you troubles later, as it is not accurate. Suppose you want to take the last soldier of your last army, `(*armys)[2][4]`.  In your scheme, you'd use `deployment[2 * armys->size()+4]`. But `armys->size()` is 3, so you'd take the element  `deployment[10]` instead of 14.  In your index "flatening" you should take the size of each line instead of the number of lines.  Assuming each army has always the same size, it would be:  `deployment[i * (*armys)[0].size()+j]` for `(*armys)[i][j]`

The initialisation loop could hence be:

```
for (int i=0; i<armys->size(); i++) 
    for (int j=0; j<(*armys)[i].size(); j++) 
        deployment[i * (*armys)[0].size()+j] = &(*armys)[i][j];
```

By the way,  as the indexing starts with 0, `(*armys)[1][2]` would be the 3rd soldier of the second army (not the first) in your text output.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/u2ZYo6)

Comment: when i do this: deployment[i * (*armys)[i].size()+j] = &(*armys)[i][j]; I am geting a ² instead of a char.

Comment: OH it seems that because i changed something it did't work that way.... Now it WORKS :D! What is the difference between (*pointername)[index].classthings and pointername[index]->classthings? I thought it was the same until now

Comment: `(*pointername)[index]`  first dereferences `pointername` to get the object pointed to (e.g. a vector) and then applies `operator[]` to that object. And `pointername[index]->...` applies immediately `operator[]` to `pointername` and then dereferences the result.  If pointername is a pointer to a vector, both syntaxex are valid, but:  the first one gets the vector and finds the right element, whereas the second one uses pointername as if it were an array of vectors ! It would hence look at the wrong memory place thinking to find there a vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it makes sense :D